# Increase RAM allowance for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, manifest, ram, visual-studio-2015

To which file am I supposed to write information that my WP8.1 application requires 300+ MB RAM? I would like to use this setup at least for the time of developing app, later I will consider other approach, targeting all devices.

As far as I can see I have only one manifest file in my project, Package.appxmanifest, shown here. I wrote the line "m3:MinDeviceMemory"1GB"/m3:MinDeviceMemory" but it doesn't seem to be enough. I have no idea where to write ID_REQ_MEMORY_300 as recommended in msdn here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx

I see no "App" object in any of my files so I can't write any "Requirements" or "FunctionalCapability" object too. Where can I find it?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest"xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest" xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/manifest" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest">
      <Identity Name="1cd9812c-28c9-4bc9-b45b-933beb09ad48" Publisher="CN=Štěpán" Version="1.0.0.0" />
      <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="1cd9812c-28c9-4bc9-b45b-933beb09ad48" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
      <Properties>
        <DisplayName>Chess Openings</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>Štěpán</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
      </Properties>
      <Prerequisites>
        <OSMinVersion>6.3.1</OSMinVersion>
        <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
        <m3:MinDeviceMemory>1GB</m3:MinDeviceMemory>
      </Prerequisites>
      <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate" />
      </Resources>
      <Applications>
        <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="Chess_Openings.App">
          <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="Chess Openings" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="Chess Openings" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="transparent">
            <m3:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\WideLogo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Square71x71Logo.png">
            </m3:DefaultTile>
            <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
            <m3:InitialRotationPreference>
              <m3:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
            </m3:InitialRotationPreference>
          </m3:VisualElements>
        </Application>
      </Applications>
      <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
      </Capabilities>
    </Package>
```

Comment: I would recommend you avoid abbreviating “Windows Phone”, if that is what you mean, to “WP”. It's not as obvious an abbreviation as you think—this is a site for programmers in general—and we get enough WordPress questions that your question may get confused with one (and closed as off-topic, since WordPress questions are largely off-topic here).

Comment: Good to know, next time I will use full name for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this my question is wrong. There is no ID_FUNCCAP_EXTEND_MEM any more in Windows Phone 8.1 compared to Windows Phone 8. This is what I was looking for all the time.

There is no default and extended memory limit in WP8.1 but just one default memory limit and it is the high one. After checking

```
Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit
```

I quickly recognized that my program wasn't failing because of insufficient memory, as I thought.

I guess

```
<m3:MinDeviceMemory>1GB</m3:MinDeviceMemory>
```

(as shown in code) can limit lower memory devices from store, but this isn't what I was looking for.